# How to use factory inside bootstrap modal [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

Here is my modal:

```
function openModal(project) 
    {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'view/addTaskTemplate.html',
            controller: 'ModalAddTaskController as modal',
            resolve: {
                detail: function () {
                    return project;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And inside `ModalAddTaskController` I am trying to call factory like this:

```
getUsersFactory.getUsers(vm.project.id)
        .then(function (data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

But get error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Anyone know what is problem?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with "how to use a factory". Your method `getUsers` seems to return nothing. You should paste the code of your factory instead.

Comment: Show your controller and factory please.

Comment: Loic you was right I didn't return data from factory. Thanks.

Comment: if getUsers is making some sort of $http.get request, remember to return the promise in your factory, like so: return $http.get('/someUrl', config), or also if you are chaining a .then call return whatever value you are changing/filtering/processing.

return $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
   return response;
  });

Answer (score 0):

The `then` property is part of the Promise API.  In your example, `getUsersFactory.getUsers(vm.project.id)` most probably isn't returning a promise object, and hence you get this error.  The factory function should be of this structure:

```
var example = angular.module('somemodule', []);

example.factory('getUsersFactory', ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http) {
  var getUsers = function(project_id) {

    // Create deferred object
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/user/list').then(function(data) {

      // Resolve the promise on success
      deferred.resolve(data);
    }, function(error) {

      // Reject the promise on error
      deferred.reject(error);
    });

    // Return the promise here
    return deferred.promise;
  }

  return {
    getUsers: getUsers
  }
}]);
```

Only after this will you be able to use something like your code:

```
getUsersFactory.getUsers(vm.project.id)
        .then(function (data)
        {
            // "data" would be the output of the resolved promise
            console.log(data);
    });
```

I hope this helps.  You can read more from here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q